# How many days in a number of years

Tags: c#

I would like to find how many days are in the amount of years that the user typed in, e.g. 8 (number of years) giving an output = 2922 days. What I am having trouble with writing is a calculation that adds an extra day for every 4 years (8 = 2 leap years).

This is what I have. This gives the right answer for 4 years with 1 leap year.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a number.");
                var year1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                var year2 = 365;
                var leap1 = 1;
                var leap2 = (year1 * year2 + leap1);
```

Cheers for the help as I am new to C#.

Comment: `year1*year2 + Math.floor(year1/4)`

Comment: "a number of years" isn't enough information. You have to know *which* years. For instance, in 6 years there could be 1 or 2 leap years.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque or even 0 leap years.

Answer (score 3):

You're not asking for enough information. If the years are 2011,2012,2013, then there is one leap year, but if they are 2013,2014,2015, there is not a leap year

```
( (year % 400 == 0) || ( (year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) ) )
```

returns true for a leap year, false for a non leap year.
Leap years are every four years, **except** on century years (1800,1900) **unless** they are also divisible by 400 (1600,2000). [Look it up](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214019). :)

For each instance of year that returns true, you add one leap day.

Answer (score 0):

Try `year1*year2 + Math.floor(year1/4)`

You just need to multiply the number of years by 365 and then add a day for every four years.

See [Rounding values up or down in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632753/rounding-values-up-or-down-in-c-sharp), for further explanation of rounding down.

However, as [Chowzen states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682104/c-sharp-how-many-days-in-a-number-of-years#39682175), this will only be accurate for an input greater than, or equal to, four.